# Prove a mapping is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, open-map, graph-embeddings

> Prove that the map $$f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}^2$$ $$t\mapsto (\cos 2\pi
>  t,\sin 2\pi t)$$ is an embedding.

PS: In general topology, an embedding is a homeomorphism onto its image. More explicitly, an injective continuous map $f:X\to Y$ between topological spaces $X, Y$  is a topological embedding if $f$  yields a homeomorphism between $X$ and $f(X)$.

I already prove $f$ is injective, continuous, but stuck at proving it yields a homeomorphism between $X$ and $f(X)$. To prove this, I'm trying to prove $g:X\to f(X)$ is homeomorphism $\iff g$ is an open mapping, which means $g(U)$ is open for every open set $U\subset X.$
Could someone help me to finish the problem? Thank in advance!

Comment: Recall that we can describe continuous mappings by how they deal with open sets, i.e. some mapping $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}(\mathcal{O})$ is open in $X$ for all open sets $\mathcal{O} \subseteq Y$.

Comment: I know, but that's not I'm stuck at.

Comment: What do you mean by "$g$ is an open mapping"? $g(U)$ open in $f(X)$? It's not the same as being open in $Y$.

Comment: Well, you're trying to prove that a homeomorphism (which admits a continuous inverse) is an open mapping. Can you see how you could apply such an idea?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Yes, $g(U)$ open in $f(X)$. But how to prove it is still a question

Comment: @kodiak Yes, but the domain of $f(X)$ is quiet complicated, so I advoid using this way. Instead, I wanna prove $g(U)$ is open in $f((0,1))$ for every open set $U\subset (0,1)$.

Comment: You need to show the image of an open set in $X$ is the intersection of an open set in $Y$ with $F(X)$. It's just a circle with a point removed so you can sketch the map easily then try to find neighborhoods in $Y$ that will work.

Comment: The easiest way to prove the inverse is continuous is by using sequences. Assume $y_n=f(x_n)$ is a sequence in the image that tends to $y=f(x)$. We need to show that this implies $x_n\to x$. It is sufficient to show that the limit of any convergent subsequence of $x_n$ must be equal to $x$. Well, that is not hard to prove using injectivity and continuity of $f$. (note also that $f$ has an extension to $[0,1]$ which allows to show that a subsequence of $x_n$ can't tend to $0$ or $1$)

Comment: Consider (for instance) the function $h:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, defined by, $h(\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t))\to (t,t)$, then consider that function $k: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $k(x,y)=\frac{x+y}{2}$. 

Use the continuity of the above functions, and write $g^{-1}$ as a composition of two continuous functions, which will be continuous.

Comment: I'm so confused. Could someone write down the comprehensible answer in the answering section? I'm very appreciated

Comment: I'm so confused. Could someone write down the comprehensible answer in the answering section? I'm very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Let $g:X\rightarrow Y$ be an injective continuous map, then $g:X\rightarrow g(X)$ is continuous bijection. Equip $g(X)\subset Y$ with the subspace topology, and suppose that $g$ is a homeomorphism. Then it follows that there is a continuous inverse $g^{-1}:g(X)\rightarrow X$. Now let $U\subset X$ be open, then we see that by definition $(g^{-1})^{-1}(U)$ is an open subset of $g(X)$, but clearly $(g^{-1})^{-1}(U)=g(U)$, so $g(U)$ and $g$ is an open map.

Now suppose that $g:X\rightarrow g(X)$ is a continuous open bijection. By the fact that $g$ is a bijection, there exists a priori a set map $g^{-1}:g(X)\rightarrow X$. Our job is to show this is continuous, so let $U\subset X$ be open, then again we have that $(g^{-1})^{-1}(U)=g(U)$, but $g$ is open so $(g^{-1})^{-1}(U)$ is open, and $g^{-1}$ is continuous implying that $g$ is a homeomorphism.

Anyways, to show this in your specific case, it suffices to prove that $f$ is open on basic opens (i.e. on the basis open sets which generate the subspace topology) of $(0,1)$, that is intervals of the. form $(a,b)$ where $0<a, b<1$. We see that $f((a,b))$ is the arc of radius one which with end points at $a2\pi$ and $b2\pi$ radians. In other words, in polar coordinates on $\mathbb R^2$, we have that:
$$f((a,b))=\{(r,\theta)\in \mathbb R^2: r=1, a2\pi<\theta<b2\pi\}$$
We also have that:
$$f((0,1))=\{(r,\theta)\in\mathbb R^2:r=1, 0<\theta<2\pi\}$$
Let $V\subset \mathbb R^2$ be the open set:
$$V=\{(r,\theta)\in \mathbb R^2:1-\epsilon <r<1+\epsilon, a2\pi<\theta<b2\pi\}$$
for some $\epsilon>0$. Then clearly we have that:
$$f((a,b))=V\cap f((0,1))$$
so $f((a,b))$ is open in the subspace topology as desired.

Comment: No, I want to prove the above exercise, not this lemma

Comment: @AlexNguyen and I quote "To prove this, I'm trying to prove $g:X\to f(X)$ is homeomorphism $\iff g$ is an open mapping, which means $g(U)$ is open for every open set $U\subset X.$"

Comment: Yes, but that the way of proving the problem, not proving the lemma

Comment: $(\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{5})\cup(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3})$ is an example of an open set in $(0,1)$ that doesn't have the form $(a,b)$ as you said. Please consider your solution.

Comment: @AlexNguyen It suffices to check this on basic open sets, i.e. the basis of open sets which generate the subspace topology on $(0,1)$. In particular, since $g$ is by construction a bijection, we have that for any $U$, $g(U)=\bigcup g(U_i)$, where $U_i$ are the basic open sets (i.e. open balls) which form $U$.

Comment: @AlexNguyen do you see what I am saying?

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to show that the images under $f$ of all elements of a subbasis for the domain $X = (0, 1)$ are open. Taking $X$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ under the order (usual) topology, one subbasis for $X$ is the collection of intervals $\{ (0, a) | 0 < a < 1 \} \cup \{ (b, 1) | 0 < b < 1 \}$.

The image of the interval $(0, a)$ ($0 < a < 1$) is an arc of the unit circle that does not include its endpoints $(1, 0)$ and $(\cos (2 \pi a), \sin (2 \pi a))$. This set is open in $f (X)$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ as a metric space with the Euclidean metric $d$: if you take any point $p = (\cos (2 \pi t), \sin (2 \pi t))$ in this set, it is contained in the set $f (X) \cap B_d \left( p, \sin \left( \pi \min \{ t, a - t \} \right) \right)$, which is open in $f (X) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and contained in the arc (as you should check).

You can perform a very similar analysis for images of subbasis elements of the form $(b, 1)$ ($0 < b < 1$).

Answer (score 0):

To prove that the map $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $t \mapsto (\cos 2\pi t, \sin 2\pi t)$ is an embedding, we need to show that it is an injective continuous map which is a homeomorphism onto its image. You've already proved that $f$ is injective.

It's evident that both components of $f$, namely $\cos 2\pi t$ and $\sin 2\pi t$, are continuous functions. Since $\cos$ and $\sin$ are continuous functions and composition of continuous functions is continuous, $f$ is continuous.

Now, to show that $f$ is a homeomorphism onto its image, we need to prove two things:

**Onto its image:** For any point $(x,y)$ in the unit circle $\mathbb{S}^1$, there exists $t$ such that $x = \cos 2\pi t$ and $y = \sin 2\pi t$ (since $\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t = 1$). Thus, every point in $\mathbb{S}^1$ is covered by $f$. Since $f$ is defined on $(0,1)$, it covers $\mathbb{S}^1$ except possibly at the points $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$. However, since $\cos$ and $\sin$ are periodic functions, the map $f$ covers $\mathbb{S}^1$ infinitely many times.

**Homeomorphism:** We need to show that $f$ is a continuous bijection and its inverse is continuous. To do this, it suffices to show that $f$ is a closed map (since $f$ is injective, it automatically has a continuous inverse, namely its restriction to its image).

To prove that $f$ is a closed map, let $A$ be any closed subset of $(0,1)$. Since $(0,1)$ is a closed subset of itself, $A$ is also closed in $(0,1)$. We want to show that $f(A)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Consider the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ in $f(A)$ converging to some point $y$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. We need to show that $y \in f(A)$. Since $f(x_n)$ converges to $y$, the sequences $\{\cos 2\pi x_n\}$ and $\{\sin 2\pi x_n\}$ must converge to $y_1$ and $y_2$ respectively, where $y = (y_1, y_2)$. Since $A$ is closed, the limit $x = \lim x_n$ is in $A$. Since $f(x_n) = (\cos 2\pi x_n, \sin 2\pi x_n)$ and both $\cos$ and $\sin$ are continuous functions, we have $f(x) = (\cos 2\pi x, \sin 2\pi x) = (y_1, y_2) = y$. Hence, $y \in f(A)$.

Thus, $f(A)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $f$ is a closed map. Since it's already continuous and injective, it is indeed an embedding.

Comment: You wrote :"Let A be any closed subset of $(0,1)$. Since $(0,1)$ is a closed subset of itself, is also closed in $(0,1)$." You already define $A$ as a closed subset in the beginning. What is the point of writing "Since $(0,1)$ is a closed subset of itself, $A$ is also closed in $(0,1)$"?
.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to show that $f : (0,1) \to f((0,1)) = S  := S^1 \setminus \{ e_1 \}$, where $e_1 = (1,0) \in S^1$, is a closed map.

Consider the continuous map
$$F : [0,1] \to S^1, F(t) = (\cos 2\pi t, \sin 2 \pi t).$$
Your map $f : (0,1) \to S$ is a restriction of $F$.

Let $C \subset (0,1)$ be closed in $(0,1)$ and $C' = \overline{C}^{[0,1]}$ be its closure in $[0,1]$. Then $C'$ is compact, hence also $F(C')$ is compact, thus closed in $S^1$. Therefore $F(C') \cap S$ is closed in $S$.

We have $C' \cap (0,1) = \overline{C}^{[0,1]} \cap (0,1) = \overline{C}^{(0,1)} = C$. With $Z = C' \cap \{0,1\} \subset \{0,1\}$ we obtain

$$C' = C' \cap (0,1) \cup C' \cap \{0,1\} = C \cup Z.$$

Since $F(Z) \subset \{ e_1 \}$ we get
$$F(C') \cap S = F(C \cup Z) \cap S = (F(C) \cup F(Z)) \cap S = (f(C) \cup F(Z)) \cap S \\= f(C) \cap S \cup F(Z) \cap S = f(C) .$$
This proves that $f(C)$ is closed in $S$.

Comment: Could you explain the part: If $C$ is not closed in $[0,1]$ then $Z$ is one of the form $\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}$?

Comment: @AlexNguyen If $C$ is not closed in $[0,1]$, then $\overline C$ contains points of $[0,1] \setminus (0,1) =\{0,1\}$.  Thus $Z \subset \{0,1\}$.

Comment: I still don't get why $\overline{C}$ must contain points of $[0,1]\setminus (0.1)=\{0,1\}$ since $C$ is not closed in $[0,1]$? :(

Comment: @AlexNguyen If $C$ is not closed in $[0,1]$, then $Z = \overline{C}^{[0,1]} \setminus C$ is non-empty. But $C$ is closed in $(0,1)$, thus $ \overline{C}^{[0,1]} \cap (0,1) = \overline{C}^{(0,1)} = C$ (see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/901291). This shows that $Z \cap (0,1) = \emptyset$.